# Objective-C NSString: strange characters when logging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

Hey all, I'm a total noob when it comes to Objective-C / iPhone development.

I'm trying to pull in text from a SQLite DB. I have a while loop that looks like this:

```
while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

And within that loop, this prints to the log just fine:

```
NSLog(@"Text: %s",sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1));
```

This does not work:

```
Category *categoryObj = [[Category alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
categoryObj.categoryName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
NSLog(@"cat name: %s",categoryObj.categoryName);
```

When I run the above and look at the logs I see:

```
cat name: ‡}00å
```

I tried to write the field out to a label, thinking it might be something specific to the NSLog but nothing shows up there. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental but I'm at a loss for what it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Log your string with `%@` instead of `%s` and you'll be fine. `NSString`s aren't pointers to characters, they're full-fledged objects, so you need to use the "object" placeholder in the log format string.

This has the added advantage of doing the right thing with non-ASCII strings and all of the other important things that `NSString` gives you.

Note that if you had just logged the result from SQLite directly instead of creating an `NSString` with it, then your `%s` would have been correct.

Remember: `%s` is for C strings, `%@` is for Objective-C objects.