# delete rows based on date

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Hi there is probably an easy answer for this, I'm just struggling to understand how to deal with it.

I create a table with:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, AGE   INTEGER, DT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

and im trying to delete a person based on there name,age and the date it was register, in order to avoid deleting a person who happened to have the same name and age of another person (therefore the current date should distinguish)

and the delete statement is:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from persons where name is '%s','%s'",[p.name UTF8String],[p.date UTF8String]]];
```

The problem im having is that '%s" must not be right for the date as its not deleting any.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7108589/2315974

Comment: I can not see how this question is not a proper question and why it should be closed. Well, anyways - that linked topic that danypata posted in his comment should get you a lot further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are quite a ways off with that delete statement.  It should be something more like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Delete from PERSONS where NAME = \"%@\" and DT = \"%@\"", p.name, p.date];
```

PERSONS and NAME need to be caps, because that's how you defined them in your create.  Your p.data will need to correspond with how sqlite stores dates.  [danypata's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108589/793607) should help you there.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you to try your query in a sql environment where you can figure out if there are any mistakes in the syntax. For me it just looks like you should use %@ instead of %s. %s is used in C, %@ in objective-c. Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1231264/1141395).

Comment: %s works it just doesnt work for date